# MySQL Show Truncate and SUM NULL values

Tags: mysql

If the Cost column is showing *NULL* how do I ignore this function and simply show *NULL*?

Currently it is omitting the results when I added this function. I tried position the COALESCE function with no luck.

**Note:** Without this select statement it shows all the entries so the JOINS are correct and the results are particular to this function.

Thanks in advance!

```
TRUNCATE(SUM(Cost/2),3) AS CostPerPart
```

Comment: without knowing the table and data have you tried `IFNULL()`? [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: if by "omitting the results" you mean not returning a row, you need to show us your query to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please feel free to provide more information but this may work depending on your structure and data. This relies on the use of `IFNULL()` The documentation is located [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

`IFNULL` will return the expression if the value is not `NULL` otherwise it will return `NULL`

> `IFNULL(expr1,expr2)`
> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `Cost` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `Cost`)
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 4.5),
    (4, 6),
    (5, NULL),
    (1, 2)
;
```

```
SELECT id
       ,IFNULL(TRUNCATE(SUM(Cost/2),3), NULL) AS CostPerPart
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id;
```

Output:

```
id  CostPerPart
1   2
2   1.5
3   2.5
4   3
5   (null)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f50863/1)

Comment: Glad it resolved your issue and best of luck to you